# How to pass and return object as parameter in JS?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an a class that takes in an object, which I want to return through a function. However, the returned type is a number which I assume to be the reference to the object.

```
class Sprite {
    constructor(img, x, y) {
        this._img = img;
        this._x = x;
        this._y = y;
    }

    get x() {
        return this._x;
    }

    setX(x) {
        this._x = x;
    }

    get y() {
        return this._y;
    }

    setY(y) {
        this._y = y;
    }

    get image() {
        return this._img;
    }
}

function main() {
    var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var avatarImage = new Image();

    avatarImage.src = "avatar.png";

    var avatar = new Sprite(150, 150, avatarImage);

   gameCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(avatar.image, avatar.x, avatar.y);
}
```

How can I return the object instead of the reference?

```
console.log(typeof(avatar.image)); // prints number instead of object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo

```
// change this
var avatar = new Sprite(150, 150, avatarImage);

// to this
var avatar = new Sprite(avatarImage, 150, 150);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I messed up the order of my own class.

Comment: No worries - it happens :)